# Printing multiplication table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to print the following:

```
Times: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
2      2  4  6  8  10 12 14 16 18
3      3  6  9  12 15 18 21 24 27
4      
5
6
7
8
9
```

I have to multiply every number in order; multiply with `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `9`. I have come this far but can't do anything further.

```
print('Times:' , end="")
for number in range(1,10):
    print(number,end="    ")
print()

for number in range(1,10):
    print(number)
```

Comment: thanks for editing before me.

Comment: And if you can , do it with 1 for loop. Please ?

Comment: For each row? Continue onto the next row? Can you elaborate on what you want?

Comment: For each row. When it comes to the end of the row , go to the next row and do the same math again until the end of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a double for-loop like this.

```
# The heading
print("Times: " , end="")
for number in range(1,10):
    print(number,end="\t")
print()

# The double for-loop
for multiplum in range(1,9):
    print(multiplum, end="      ") # First column
    for number in range(1,10):
        print(multiplum*number, end="\t") # Next 9 columns
    print()
```

Comment: Great. I've just edited my answer. Now the numbers are separated by tabs.

Comment: Hello again. I add an input option to this code. But if i enter a number bigger than 9 , the spaces are going crazy. How can we fix this ?

Comment: LOL. The problem was that the window was too small for it ! lmao

Comment: Just fine. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

The code is python 2.x supported you have to change the print statement as per your need

**Code:**

```
print'Times:' ,
for number1 in range(1,10):
    print number1,
print 
for number2 in range(1,10):
    print number2,"\t",
    for number3 in range(1,10):
        print number3*number2,
    print
```

**Output:**

```
Times: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2       2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
3       3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
4       4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
5       5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
6       6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
7       7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
8       8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
9       9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Comment: Thank you but i couldnt change this exactly. Every number uses a new row ? Fixed it thank you so much for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

You were half-way there; you can simply use a nested `for` loop. Essentially what you're saying here is: I want to multiply each number from 1-9 by each number from 1-9.

```
for a in range(1,10): #for each number as a in range from 1-9 do
    for b in range(1,10): # take each number b from range 1-9 and 
        print(a*b) #..print the product of a and b.
```

Comment: Vignesh got it better - I left out the formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution uses numpy arrays to compute the table for an alternative solution

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([[str(i*j).zfill(2) for j in xrange(1,10)] for i in 

xrange(1,10)])

print 'Times:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09'
for i in xrange(9):
    print str(i+1).zfill(2), '\t',
    print str(l[i]).replace('\'','').replace('[','').replace(']','')

Times:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
01      01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
02      02 04 06 08 10 12 14 16 18
03      03 06 09 12 15 18 21 24 27
04      04 08 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
05      05 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
06      06 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
07      07 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
08      08 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
09      09 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

If it doesn't matter if the `Times:` is in the corner you can do it in two lines using pandas like so

```
import pandas as pd
labels = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
print pd.DataFrame(data=([[i*j for j in xrange(1,10)] for i in xrange(1,10)]), columns = labels, index = labels)

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
3  3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
4  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36
5  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
6  6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54
7  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63
8  8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72
9  9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

And if you want the `Times:` and to make it fancy you could combine it with tabulate

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
from pandas import DataFrame
labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=( [ [i*j for j in xrange(1,10)] for i in xrange(1,10)] ), index = labels)

print tabulate(df, headers=['Times:']+labels,tablefmt = 'fancy_grid', numalign='left')

╒══════════╤═════╤═════╤═════╤═════╤═════╤═════╤═════╤═════╤═════╕
│ Times:   │ 1   │ 2   │ 3   │ 4   │ 5   │ 6   │ 7   │ 8   │ 9   │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1        │ 1   │ 2   │ 3   │ 4   │ 5   │ 6   │ 7   │ 8   │ 9   │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 2        │ 2   │ 4   │ 6   │ 8   │ 10  │ 12  │ 14  │ 16  │ 18  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 3        │ 3   │ 6   │ 9   │ 12  │ 15  │ 18  │ 21  │ 24  │ 27  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 4        │ 4   │ 8   │ 12  │ 16  │ 20  │ 24  │ 28  │ 32  │ 36  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 5        │ 5   │ 10  │ 15  │ 20  │ 25  │ 30  │ 35  │ 40  │ 45  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 6        │ 6   │ 12  │ 18  │ 24  │ 30  │ 36  │ 42  │ 48  │ 54  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 7        │ 7   │ 14  │ 21  │ 28  │ 35  │ 42  │ 49  │ 56  │ 63  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 8        │ 8   │ 16  │ 24  │ 32  │ 40  │ 48  │ 56  │ 64  │ 72  │
├──────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 9        │ 9   │ 18  │ 27  │ 36  │ 45  │ 54  │ 63  │ 72  │ 81  │
╘══════════╧═════╧═════╧═════╧═════╧═════╧═════╧═════╧═════╧═════╛
```

Answer (score 0):

it's okk 
i'm coding in python :
try out this one :

```
print 'Times:' ,
for number in range(1,10):
    print "%d"% (number),

for i in range(1,10):
    print ""    
    print i,"    :",

    for number in range(1,10):
        print number*i ,
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :) Have a nice day